# Как получить данные от пользователя на vkbottle

Tags: python, python-3.x

Народ, помогите пожалуйста. Хочу сделать такую штуку в боте, чтобы можно было делать смешные ники. Для этого пользователь должен ввести команду Бот мне ник *ник* и как мне получить этот самый *ник* и записать его в переменную?

Answer (score 0):

для этого оказывается нужно было просто в декоратор передать параметр text с содержимым "Бот мне ник " и в параметры самой функции указать nick=None